# Deleting record from table is not actually deleting VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table called Scenarios that has a 1 to many relationship with ESDNodes. There can be multiple ESDNodes that reference a single Scenario.

For every Scenario there must be at least one ESDNode which means that when a scenario is to be deleted, all of its related ESDNodes must then be deleted.

So when the user selects a scenario and attempts to delete it, this function is called:

```
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim scenID As Long
  Dim ESDHeadNodeID As Long
  Dim response As Long
  Dim style As Long

  scenID = Forms!Main!Scenarios!ScenarioID
  ESDHeadNodeID = DLookup("ESDNodeID", "ESDNodes", "((ESDNodes.ESDNodeType)=1) AND ((ESDNodes.ScenarioID) = " & scenID & ")")

  style = vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion
  response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete all selected nodes and their children?", style)
  If response = vbYes Then
     DeleteESDChildren (ESDHeadNodeID)
     loadESDTreeView
  End If
End Sub
```

In DeleteESDChildren is where I handle deleting all relevant ESDNodes. I removed all code that is irrelevant to the error in this function. 
Here is that function:

```
Public Function DeleteESDChildren(lngID As Long)
  Dim rst_Del As Recordset
  Set rst_Del = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ESDNodes WHERE ESDNodeID = " & lngID)

  rst_Del.MoveFirst

  'Delete the head node
  If Not rst_Del.EOF Then
     rst_Del.Delete 
  End If
End Function
```

I tested this code with the simplest case where there is only one ESDNode for a scenario and the ESDNode has no children. The line that calls rst_Del.Delete, I expect to delete this singular ESDNode. But instead I get an error when the Form_Delete attempts to End Sub claiming "The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'ESDNodes' includes related records." So this singular ESDNode is not getting deleted.

Screenshot showing the relationships between my tables
[image: Screenshot showing the relationships between my tables]

Comment: How do you get to that line? It looks like you're in a loop in the first 5 lines of DeleteESDChildren. No?

Comment: I edited it so that all irrelevant code to the error is not in the function including that loop. Should be more clear to follow now.

Comment: Fwiw, i might start with `If rst_Del.EOF Then Exit Sub` then MoveLast and get the recordcount to make sure you have some rows.

Comment: A few more good ideas to follow here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html.

Comment: is there any reason why you do not use a SQL `delete` query instead of the `select` query to delete the related ESDnodes ?   .... then run another delete query to remove the scenario record.

Comment: Please post screenshot of your relationships diagram (Ribbon > Database Tools > Relationships), focused on *ESDnodes*.

Comment: @Parfait I am sorry it took a while but I have now posted a screenshot of my relationships diagram.

Comment: Interesting, you have quite a bit of links to *ESINodes* and what looks to be the same table referential integrity. It looks like *FTNodes* is a child table, so you have to delete all corresponding rows there first before deleting from *ESINodes*. But *ESINode_1* may also be a problem.

Comment: if you're enforcing cascade delete between `scenarios` and `esdNodes`, all you should have to do is delete the parent row from the `scenarios` table.

Comment: also, fyi, it's easier to read relationship diagrams if the '1' tables are to the left, 'many' tables to the right, so you see parents on the left and related children to the parent's right.

Comment: when you delete an `esdNodeID`, you'll also need to delete related IDs from `ftNodes`.

Comment: I am already deleting all related FTNodes and ESDNodes. I did not demonstrate this in the code I have posted here so as not to add clutter but that part is well tested and am confident that it is working. Furthermore, I am getting this error in the simplest case in which a Scenario refers to a singular ESDNode which has no other ESDNodes children or FTNodes.

Comment: My issue was that loadESDTreeView was recreating the record that was just deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using SQL

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM ESDNodes WHERE ESDNodeID = " & lngID
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're in a loop.

```
Public Function DeleteESDChildren(lngID As Long)
    Dim rst As Recordset
    'find the children of the node
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ESDNodes WHERE ParentID = " & lngID)

    'call deletechildren on each child in turn
    While Not rst.EOF
        DeleteESDChildren (rst!ESDNodeID) '<-- goes back to the beginning.
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    etc.
```

Comment: That line is for deleting the children of that ESDNode. In other words there is a 1 to many relationship for ESDNodes to other ESDNodes. But I am testing the code with the simplest test case where it is just one ESDNode with no children so that recordset will be empty and that loop will not enter.

Comment: I suppose I can comment that code out so as not to confuse anybody

Comment: ah i see what u did there.